# Selling price or selling prices

Tags: plural-forms, singular

Check out this sentence:

> "As the **selling price** of hardware, building materials as well as IT products were under downward pressure due to stiff competition, the company's business environment is expected to be remain challenging in the coming few quarters."

Should I use 'selling prices' instead of 'selling price'?

Comment: Side note: The construction "hardware, building materials as well as IT products" is awkward. "As well as" indicates something of an afterthought. The sentence should be grammatically correct without it. "As the selling price of hardware, building materials were under ..." does not work. You should say either, "As the selling prices of hardware and building materials, as well as IT products, were ..." or "As the selling prices of hardware, building materials, and IT products were ..."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use *prices* because the following verb you used is plural - *were*. This means you are using two prices - the price of hardware and building material **and** the price of IT products.

> "As the selling **prices** of hardware, building materials as well as IT products **were** under downward pressure due to stiff competition, the company's business environment is expected to be remain challenging in the coming few quarters."

Note that you can use *plural prices* for single entity there because that entity itself contains *products*. For instance, *The prices of IT products --considering several products' prices.*

The word *[price](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/price_1)* is countable and uncountable both.

You may consider a better version of the sentence as suggested by Jay and Damkerng: *As the selling prices of hardware and building materials, as well as IT products, were under downward...*

Comment: I think this answer is good enough for the OP's question. I also agree with Jay that "as well as" here is awkward; however, it's probably what the OP wanted to say. I think a comma before *as well as* and another after *IT products* could improve the sentence a little.